# AST module ['zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 2 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 7 ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-structures, abstract-syntax-tree

I have a pandas data frame, It contains a column that looks like this

```
0    [zero, zero, zero, zero, 2, zero, zero, zero, ...
1    [zero, zero, zero, 3, zero, zero, zero, 4, zer...
2    [zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, 2, ...
3    [1, zero, 6, 1, zero, zero, zero, zero, zero, ...
4    [zero, zero, zero, zero, 6, zero, zero, [2, 0]...
Name: y, dtype: object
```

this column is the output of this function

```
def santa(the_frame):

    g = dict([[key, [*g]] for key, g in groupby(the_frame, key=lambda x: (x-1)//7)])

    #d = [((list([c%7 for c in g[i]]) if len(g[i]) > 1 else g[i][0]%7) if (i in g) else 'zero') for i in range(0, 143))]    

    d = np.array([((np.array([c%7 for c in g[i]], dtype=object) if len(g[i]) > 1 else g[i][0]%7) if (i in g) else 'zero') for i in range(0, 143)])    


    return(d)
```

I was trying to remove the `0` in the last line inside the list`[2,0]`

I tried this

```
x['y'] = x['y'].astype(str).str.replace('0', '7').apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

which was working fine but then I tried replacing the list expression in my function with a Numpy array as in the final line of the function and now it gives me this error  when I run the line above

```
['zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 2 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 'zero' 7            ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what is the problem here and how do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this? `x['y'] = x['y'].apply(lambda x: str(x)).str.replace('0', '7').apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: same error again

Comment: I'm wondering how it gets to this situation. Maybe... `x['y'] = x['y'].apply(lambda x: str(x.tolist())).str.replace('0', '7').apply(ast.literal_eval)`

Comment: Now I get this error ValueError: malformed node or string: <_ast.Call object at 0x124af56d8>

Comment: Can you print this: `(x['y'].iloc[0].dtype)`? It seems like your cells are now numpy arrays which are being printed out with a screwed up repr.

Comment: the output is dtype('O')

Comment: Okay, I tried `x['y'] = x['y'].apply(lambda x: str(x.tolist())).str.replace('0', '7').apply(ast.literal_eval)` and it worked for me. Something is wrong with your kernel. Just restart it and try again.

Comment: The error is _exactly_ because they are numpy arrays.

Comment: I restarted my kernel and I got the same error, I tried running the code on Idle and Atom and through the terminal but the same error always

Comment: Any other Ideas please or another way I could use